# ConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3a5d760390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')

Tags: python

I am facing Connection Error with urllib which is used by FHIR_parser. This error happens in a GET request to the endpoint which accepts the patient id. Link to repository : https://github.com/greenfrogs/FHIR-Parser

requests - 2.24.0, urllib3 version : 1.25.10, python : 3.7

```
>> from fhir_parser import FHIR
>> fhir = FHIR()
>> patient = fhir.get_patient('8f789d0b-3145-4cf2-8504-13159edaa747')
```

Connection Error

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
(self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
raise err
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3a5d760390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/Patient/8f789d0b-3145-4cf2-8504-13159edaa747 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3a5d760390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhir_parser/fhir.py", line 73, in get_patient
response = requests.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(self.endpoint, 'Patient/' + str(id)), verify=self.verify_ssl)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/Patient/8f789d0b-3145-4cf2-8504-13159edaa747 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3a5d760390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: Looks like your library expects some server running on your local machine on port 5001. Look at libary's description, probably you need to run some command to start server.

Comment: Or may be you should contact some server to receive data. Because definitely library downloads data from remote server. It is probably that server is running on local host by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library is just a FHIR client, there's no server. So you must provide FHIR server's address/URL, by default it expects server to be run on local host and port 5001, and uses URL like `https://localhost:5001/api/`. Or you need to run FHIR server yourself on local host.

```
from fhir_parser import FHIR
fhir = FHIR(endpoint = 'https://SomeServer.com:SomePort/api/')
print(fhir.get_patient('8f789d0b-3145-4cf2-8504-13159edaa747'))
```